# Iterating over dictionary with wildcard key matching

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary in order to retrieve all values that match the pattern `npi[0-9]+` for the key. Is this possible in Python?

```
for data in input_file:
    print(data['npi0'])
    print(data['npi1'])
    ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just iterate over your dictionary, and do a pattern match on the key.

```
for key in dict:
    if re.match(r'npi[0-9]+', key):
        print(dict[key])
```